# Jsoup Grab embedded tags

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am using Jsoup and was wondering how do you get embedded tags? I can get the section tag but I am not sure how to get the div tag inside as I have a list of elements. My question is how do I fetch a div tag inside a section tag?

[image: HTML Page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work surely

> Elements elements = doc.select("section.page-content-full div.content");

Comment: Thanks a ton both solutions worked! however, the web page has a loading div tag before the store listing div tag. I am receiving the loading div tag but not the store listing div tag. Any help would be vastly appreciated. Here is my output..

Comment: <div class="content"> 
 <h1 class="title"> Airdrie store listing(s)</h1> 
 <p class="store-list-intro" data-store-message="There are {0} stores in Airdrie" data-nostore-message="No stores  available in
                    &nbsp;Airdrie"> </p> 
 <div class="loader"> 
  <img src="/etc/designs/lclonline/images/global/loader.gif" alt=""> 
  <p> Loading...</p> 
 </div> 
</div>
>

Answer (score 1):

Just use the query selector syntax :

```
Elements elems = doc.select("section.main-page-content-full>div.content");
```

If you want just the first element use the following :

```
Elements elems = doc.select("section.main-page-content-full>div.content").first();
```